# How can we extend the notion of unique factorization monoid to arbitrary products?

Tags: infinite-product, monoid, unique-factorization-domains

We have a precise definition of unique factorization monoid that concerns products of finitely many elements. How can we extend it to arbitrary products, as the ones that we find in McKenzie's article "Cardinal multiplication of structures with a reflexive relation"? Did someone do this before?